# checkbox attributed checked but the opposite checkbox that does not have the attribute checked is selected

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

my checkboxes are acting strangely or maybe I am missing something but cannot get my finger on it.

I have two checkboxes of the same name and the one with the attribute Checked="checked" is not showing as checked. Instead the other attribute that does not contain the checked attribute shows as checked.
I am missing anything? 
Below is my html:

```
<input checked="checked" id="EditLearnerReadOnly" name="EditLearner" type="radio" value="False"> ReadOnly

<input id="EditLearnerFullAccess" name="EditLearner" type="radio" value="True"> Full Access
```

The browser shows Full Access as the checked one.

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: You need to show your code, not a link to an image of it.

Comment: from your code inside screenshot it doesn't seems like it's a `checkbox`

Comment: There is a significant difference in both the semantics and in the functionality of "checkbox" versus "radio button" - which are you trying to use?

Answer (score -1):

Show the Code First..We try to give best answer.
You can try this

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="true" /> see
```